# Changing logistic regression's loss function

Tags: logistic, loss-functions

We're using logistic regression to predict events probability. Logistic regression tries to  minimize the residual variance (sum of squared residuals). However, in our specific problem we would like to use a different loss function (for the errors in the logistic regression).
Does anyone knows any implementation (or how to implement) such change? (preferably in R or Python)
Thanks!

Comment: The typical approach to fitting logistic regression models is via maximum likelihood. This is not equivalent to minimizing the variance of the residuals.

Comment: What kind of loss function are you interested in? You can always use general-purpose nonlinear minimization functions, but often there are better application-specific approaches.

Comment: But is there any other method to fit a logit function to a 0s & 1s response using a different loss function?

Comment: there are several different functions. I get the "score" for the probabilities estimation according to these functions, so I want, the fitted function to be estimated according to those "scores" (and not just by using maximum likelihood

Comment: Logistic regression *is* iteratively reweighted least squares. Perhaps the generalization this person is after is an iteratively reweighted optimization for a different objective function. But choosing such weights... I don't know. If the goal is developing a predictive algorithm, then this approach is in left field, as prediction for binary and continuous outcomes are as apples and oranges.

Comment: @Adam: I think it's probably more accurate to say that "a *maximum-likelihood fit* of a logistic regression model *can be* implemented by an iterative reweighted least-squares algorithm." Condensing that to "... *is* ..." seems a little strong to me. Cheers. :)

Comment: @cardinal: Can you explain when logistic regression isn't maximum likelihood? Models with different links or objective functions go by different names, as far as I know. Equivalently, can you explain when Fisher Scoring and Newton-Raphson or iteratively reweighted LS aren't the same for estimating a logistic regression model?

Comment: Do you intend to change the cost function?

If that is the case you could take a look at [Scipy Optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) which 
offers some python functions to minimize your problem given 
a (cost) function that you supply.

Comment: @Adam: The logistic regression model is logically separate from the means by which one fits it. The model simply says that each observation is distributed as a Bernoulli independently of the other observations and with a probability that is a particular function of additional covariates. Choosing to fit such a model by maximum likelihood is an entirely separate matter. Choosing to *implement* a maximum-likelihood fit by IRLS is yet another, separate, matter.

Comment: It would be necessary to specify the desired loss to give any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Estimation is usually by maximizing the likelihood function. May be you can try probit instead of logit or other link function.  I am not sure will this help you

Comment: Why can't I add comments to the original question? I am new to this forum

Comment: There is no way to answer the question (other than pointing out that it contained a false assumption) without knowing the ultimate goal of the analysis.

Comment: @vinux: See the [reputation section](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) of the FAQ. (Total reputation of 50 is needed to comment everywhere.)